# Contractor accidentally got paint on our brand new cabinets. How do I proceed?

Tags: painting, cabinets, renovation

Our contractor who we hired for a renovation of our kitchen and living room got a bit hasty and installed the cabinets and flooring before he was done with the drywall work. The day before they were going to paint, I left out a roll of plastic barrier so they could use it while painting. I showed up on Friday after work, I found out they have gotten a decent amount of paint on our new cabinets, laminate floors and even some of the pictures we had on the wall. Now the new cabinets have a nice film of gypsum dust from the drywall work and paint!  I texted him after I saw the paint on the cabinets expressing my concern for damaging the cabinet finish. I plan on talking to the contractor tomorrow about how we should address this issue. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: The contractor is in deep do-do.  They need to remove the paint and have the cabinets and floor and pictures return to new condition.  Contractor better hope they can remove the paint without leaving stains/marks.

Comment: They make it like new, or they (or their liability insurance - unless you went with a fly-by-night *uninsured* contractor) buy you new cabinets, flooring, and pictures.

Comment: No one can take advantage of you without your permission. *You must stand firm.* Decide in advance how you want the situation rectified and accept nothing less.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a legal issue than a home improvement one. Hopefully you haven't already paid the contractor in full and even then, what you didn't pay might not be enough to cover replacement of your damaged items if need be. Keep records of your discussions with him and get his company involved, if he has one, if he's not taking the responsibility to fix the items so they look like new. This is your new kitchen, you'll be looking at it for years so you need to be firm and don't settle for anything less than like new. You have agencies like the Better Business Bureau and social media that you can make complaints to should the need rise.